# How to declare a function that returns an array in glsl es (version 100)

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, glsles

The following shader method:

```
float[1] GetArray()
{
    float array[1];
    array[0] = 1.0;
    return array;
}
```

Gives me:
ERROR: 0:1: 'GetArray' : syntax error: Array size must appear after variable name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a way to work around this limitation.
You can return an array by modifying the passed in array by reference.
Here is a sample fragment shader:

```
void GetArray(inout vec4 array[1])
{
    array[0] = vec4(.5,.2,.1,1.0);
} 

void main()
{
    vec4 test[1];
    GetArray(test);
    gl_FragColor = test[0];
}
```